# docker container don't stop

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to launch a network of containers using docker-compose, when I want to stop this network I executed

```
  docker-compose down
```

some containers didn't stop, I tried

```
  docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
```

but it didn't execute, I receive no response after running this command!
I have tried this command also :

```
docker rm id_container
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to force this container to stop?

Comment: Can you share your docker daemon logs?

Comment: Please show the output of `docker ps` before and after you attempt to stop the container and include the inspect output for the container after you run stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop all containers with the following command:`docker stop $(docker ps -q)`

also you can force to remove a container `docker rm -f container_id`

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes docker hangs and compose services become ghost services with status pending removal or something like that. Try to restart your host and see if that helps solving the problem.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. I don't know why the OP marked the answer that he did, because he himself says he solved his problem by restarting his PC.

Answer (score 1):

You must stop the container before removing them. Use `docker-compose stop && docker-compose rm -f`.

Comment: it didn't worked: it displays: ERROR: An HTTP request took too long to complete. Retry with --verbose to obtain debug information.

Comment: Show me the logs with `docker-compose logs`. Try restarting the service using `sudo service docker restart`.

Comment: I restarted the PC and the problem was resolved after!